# WWDR intermediate certificate expiration and existing signitures

Tags: macos, app-store, keychain, provisioning

Will I need to create a new Developer Id Application signature?
Or is the existing one will still be valid after WWDR intermediate certificate expiration? (14 Feb) I'm using it for mac osx applications.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create any new Developer ID, Development Certificate , Production certificate after expiration of WWDR Intermediate Certificate.

> Do I need to regenerate any of my certificates?
>
> No. Your existing
>   certificates will work with both the expiring and the renewed
>   intermediate certificate.

If you still face any issue with your iOS Apps , Mac Apps, Safari Extension, Apple Wallet and Safari Push Notifications, then please follow this link of [WWDR Intermediate Certificate expiration](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/).